# How to programmatically adding a label control into a web form?

Tags: .net, label

How do I add a label next to a textbox during runtime in asp.net? Unlike window form, I can't set the location of the control. So how do I instantiate a label and set the location next to a declared textbox?

Or may be adding a string like "<span>my message</span>" next to the textbox will work for me as well.

Thank you.

Comment: If you give us a little more detail, as to what the purpose of the label, or messages are, we might be able to offer more solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is to put a regular label control on the webform at the desired location and manage its visibility in the code behind.

Comment: That's the worse case I will do because I have a big list of textbox.

Comment: I would have done the same too. But here the case is that there are too many controls.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this MSDN page: [Adding Controls to a Web Forms Page Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1(v=VS.100).aspx)

Using the [AddAt method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.addat(v=VS.100).aspx) will allow you to position the control within the control tree structure of the page.

You have a lot of control over how you can add controls dynamically to a page.